# Access function protocol in generic class

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, generics, protocols

I want to access function in protocol, but XCode complaint

> Instance member 'createColumns' cannot be used on type 'T'; did you
>   mean to use a value of this type instead?

What I have done:

Create protocol:

```
protocol StorageModelDelegate {
   func createColumns(for tableBuilder: TableBuilder)
}
```

Create class generic that receive StorageModelDelegate:

```
class SQLiteStorage<T: StorageModelDelegate> {
     func createTable(tableName: TableKey) -> Bool {
           let table = Table(tableName.rawValue)

           let query = table.create(ifNotExists: true) { (builder: TableBuilder) in
                T.createColumns(for: builder) // -> this is the error comes up.
           }
     }
}
```

Create class that implement SQLiteStorage:

```
final class InfoStorageModel {
    private let sqlite: SQLiteStorage = SQLiteStorage<Info>()
}
```

so, how to fix the error in SQLiteStorage class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to call static method instead of instance method.

In order to fix, you should add instance parameter:

First of all, use weak var delegate in order to prevent retain cycles.

```
protocol StorageModelDelegate: class {
   func createColumns(for tableBuilder: TableBuilder)
}

final class SQLiteStorage<T: StorageModelDelegate> {
weak var delegate: T?
     func createTable(tableName: TableKey) -> Bool {
           let table = Table(tableName.rawValue)

           let query = table.create(ifNotExists: true) { (builder: TableBuilder) in
                delegate?.createColumns(for: builder)
           }
     }
}
```

Or use static protocol methods:

```
protocol StorageModelDelegate {
   static func createColumns(for tableBuilder: TableBuilder)
}


final class SQLiteStorage<T: StorageModelDelegate> {
weak var delegate: T?
     func createTable(tableName: TableKey) -> Bool {
           let table = Table(tableName.rawValue)

           let query = table.create(ifNotExists: true) { (builder: TableBuilder) in
                T.createColumns(for: builder)
           }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The error indicates that you need an *instance* of `T`, not the *type* itself.

So you need something like:

```
class SQLiteStorage<T: StorageModelDelegate> {
    var delegate:T

    init (delegate:T) {
      self.delegate = delegate
    }

    func createTable(tableName: TableKey) -> Bool {
          let table = Table(tableName.rawValue)

          let query = table.create(ifNotExists: true) { (builder: TableBuilder) in
                self.delegate.createColumns(for: builder) // -> this is the error comes up.
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I go with @Vyacheslav's solution, because if I use your answer, I need to pass the delegate parameter when I create SQLiteStorage object.
Something like:
`let storage = SQLiteStorage<Info>(delegate: Info())`